# How to find app properies in 20:04

Tags: google-chrome, launcher

For exemple,in Ubuntu 14:04 you can add a link from the launcher to the desktop and then right-click and open properties an add "google-chrome --password-store=basic" in  Command:

But this is not possibly in Ubuntu 20:04. I have tried to go to Settings --> Application --> Chromium, but there are no way to add something in Command: as above.

/Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If this concerns a launcher that you placed on the desktop, then find the corresponding `.desktop` file in your Desktop folder, open it with a text editor and edit the `Exec=` line.

For a launcher that appears in the Application overview which you want to edit, copy the launcher .desktop file from the system folder `/usr/share/applications` (or possibly other places for applications installed as a snap package) to the folder `.local/share/applications` under your home folder. `.local` is a hidden folder. Turn "view hidden files" on in the file manager to see that folder in your home folder. Customize the launcher by editing the `.desktop` file.